# Using php to return GROUP_CONCAT('column x') values

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I am trying to use PHP to return SQL values into an HTML table.  I am able to get every column to populate without a problem except for the last column, `"GROUP _ CONCAT (provision_id)."`

Relevant code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$contents = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT salaries.id, name, remaining, contract_value, GROUP_CONCAT( provision_id ) FROM salaries LEFT JOIN contracts ON contracts.id = salaries.id GROUP BY salaries.id"));

 ?>

   [table header stuff...]

<?php 

    foreach ($contents as $content) {
        ?>   
             <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $content->name ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $content->remaining ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $content->contract_value ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $content->GROUP_CONCAT(provision_id) ?></td>

    <?php }; ?>   

            </tr>
```

Just echoing `$content->provision-id` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an [alias for the column](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_alias.asp).
`GROUP_CONCAT( provision_id ) as pids
...
echo $content->pids`

Answer (score 4):

If you are fetching into objects, you should give your columns names that are legal class member identifiers in PHP (I'll link to the manual, although their [description of valid variable names](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) is horrible):

```
SELECT ... GROUP_CONCAT(provision_id) AS provisions
```