# Pulling data from 2 separate mysql tables, echo matching records on same table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables, one that stores box numbers and one that saves the contents of each box. Whereas before I used to save this all on one table, for example column 1 = box number, column 2 = box contents in comma separated format, I now have table 'move_items' column 1 = box number, table 'move_contents' column 1 = box number, table 'move_contents' column 2 = box contents.

The problem I'm now finding is that although I can echo the results in a `<table>`, I'm getting separate rows for the same box that contains multiple contents:

[image]

What I want instead is if box number 2 contains 2 items, I want this to show on only one row with both items under the 'contents' column:

[image]

My currently query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT move_items.*, move_contents.* FROM move_items LEFT JOIN move_contents ON move_items.boxnumber = move_contents.box ORDER BY move_items.date DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row["boxnumber"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["boxcontents"].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

I am at a complete loss now. Before I go back to the old inefficient way of storing all the box contents in one comma separated cell, can anyone help me out? I've tried many things such as GROUP BY but my inexperience is showing.

Comment: you would need to lose the 2nd `<td></td>` and then move that array into the first one and just add a comma between results and trim off the trailing one. You can also CONCAT() the results in that same `<td>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `group by` and `group_concat`:

```
SELECT mi.*, group_concat(mc.contents)
FROM move_items mi LEFT JOIN
     move_contents mc
     ON mi.boxnumber = mc.box
GROPU BY mi.boxnumber
ORDER BY mi.date DESC;
```

Comment: Sure, but look at the screenshots of what they're getting now, as opposed to how it's laid out.

Comment: Oh yeah I remember now; you don't do PHP. So the OP will need a separate answer and combine them to produce the results that they want. I guess I answered it in comments ;-)

Comment: I replaced my old select statement with this one, slight edit to the beginning 
`SELECT mi.*, mc.contents, group_concat(mc.contents)` and the GROUP typo, however only one box content is currently showing for box number 20 despite two rows in the move_contents table. I'm going to have to check this up in the morning as I'm now brain dead :-(

Comment: ok I got back from dinner and I finally found out how to use this answer, I simply went `SELECT mi.*, group_concat(mc.contents) as thecontents` and in my php I echo'd this using `$row["thecontents"]`, thanks Gordon and @FunkFortyNiner! I used the answers from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154278/using-php-to-return-group-concatcolumn-x-values.